# How to convert MongoDB query in Laravel 5?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, laravel-5

I created mongodb query which I have to use in laravel controller. I tried to convert into Laravel 5.

My query is as follows:

```
  db.project_Data.aggregate(
    {
        $project:{
            UPSTempStatus:1
        } 
    },
    { 
        $unwind : "$UPSTempStatus" 
    },
    {   
        $match: 
        {
            UPSTempStatus: {$ne:null} 
        } 
    },
    {   
        $group : { 
            _id:null, 
            totalcount : {$sum:1},
            LowTemp: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",0]},1,0]
                    }},
            HighTemp: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",2]},1,0]
                    }},
            NormalTemp: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",1]},1,0]
                    }},
            Error4: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",4]},1,0]
                    }},
            Error5: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",5]},1,0]
                    }},
    }},
    {$project:
    {
        LowTempPer:{ 
            $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$LowTemp","$totalcount"]},100]
        } , 
        NormalTempPer:{ 
            $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$NormalTemp","$totalcount"]},100]
        },
        HighTempPer:{ 
            $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$HighTemp","$totalcount"]},100]
        }
    }} ,
    {$sort: {_id:-1}}
);
```

I try to use Laravel raw but show error like `Unrecognized parameter to $cond: $eq`. I don't no how to covert in to Laravel 5.2.

In laravel 5.2

```
$result = project_Data::raw(function ($collection){
        return $collection->aggregate(array(
            array('$project' => array('UPSTempStatus' =>1)),
            array('$unwind' => '$UPSTempStatus'),
            array('$match' => array('UPSTempStatus'  => array('$ne' => null))),
            array('$group' => array(
                '_id' => null,
                'totalcount' => array('$sum' => 1),
                'LowTemp' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 0 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                'HighTemp' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 2 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                'NormalTemp' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 1 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                'Error4' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 4 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                'Error5' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 5 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ]
            )),
            array('$project' => array(
                'LowTempPer' => array('$multiply' => array('$divide' => array('$LowTemp', '$totalcount'), 100)),
                'NormalTempPer' => array('$multiply' => array('$divide' => array('$NormalTemp', '$totalcount'), 100)),
                'HighTempPer' => array('$multiply' => array('$divide' => array('$HighTemp', '$totalcount'), 100)),
            )),
            array(
                '_id' => -1
            )
        ));
    })->toArray();
```

After coverting in laravel get response error is `this object is already an operator expression, and can't be used as a document expression (at '0')`
Please suggest me how to solve this or how to convert into laravel query?

Comment: @chridam i update the question

Comment: Any specific reason why you are mixing the square bracket array notation `[]` with the `array()` notation?

Comment: @chridam Yes, because if i use array instated of [], get error "Unrecognized parameter to $cond: $eq"

Comment: Try this it might help.. Even though, I had some issues with this package as well but still it works fine. [Laravel MongoDB Eloquent](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb)

Comment: @Abbasi i tried this but not working

Comment: Try to use DB::getQueryLog(), might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = project_Data::raw(function ($collection){
            return $collection->aggregate(array(
                array('$project' => array('UPSTempStatus' =>1)),
                array('$unwind' => '$UPSTempStatus'),
                array('$match' => array('UPSTempStatus'  => array('$ne' => null))),
                array('$group' => array(
                    '_id' => null,
                    'totalcount' => array('$sum' => 1),
                    'LowTemp' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 0 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                    'HighTemp' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 2 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                    'NormalTemp' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 1 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                    'Error4' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 4 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ],
                    'Error5' => [ '$sum' => [ '$cond' => [ [ '$eq' => [ '$UPSTempStatus', 5 ] ], 1, 0 ] ] ]
                )),
                array('$project' => array(
                    '_id' =>0,
                    'LowTempPer' => array('$multiply' => array(100, array('$divide' => ['$LowTemp', '$totalcount']))),
                    'HighTemp' => array('$multiply' => array(100, array('$divide' => ['$HighTemp', '$totalcount']))),
                    'NormalTemp' => array('$multiply' => array(100, array('$divide' => ['$NormalTemp', '$totalcount'])))
                ))
            ));
        });
```